# Why don't three T*'s (T*T*T*) appear if I type three of them after each other in a question or comment field?

Tags: support, formatting

I don't know if this is the appropriate place to ask, but when I type three T*'s directly after each other the following string of symbols appears: T*T*T* (I typed three T*'s). What's the cause of this? Obviously, it has nothing to to with my computer because in the title field this doesn't happen. If I type three V*'s: V*V*V*.

Comment: TTT i tried what you have mentioned seems to be working fine . What system are you using?

Comment: @ShubhamSinghrawat I typed three times a T* (like in the title field, where nothing changes), without a space between them: T*T*T*. You see what comes out.

Comment: Which computer system are you using?

Answer (score 4):

`*stuff*` is for italic formatting. To insert an actual *, type a backslash before the star: `\*`

But I suspect that you're looking for math formatting: $T^*T^*$ typed `$T^*T^*$`.

For more information, look at the bar with formatting buttons above the edit box, and follow the link to the help center.

Comment: T\*T\*T\* I actually typed a T a \ and a * three times. Let's see...

Comment: Gilles, thanks, man!